# Count grouped results

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have to count how many results countains columns b, for example:

I created this query to explain my problem:

```
  Declare @t as Table(a varchar(50), b varchar(50))
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'LOBO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('DOS', 'LOBO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'PERRO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('DOS', 'PERRO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'GATO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'POLLO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'PATO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'PATO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'PATO');
  Insert into @t (a,b) values ('UNO', 'PATO');

    select b,a from @t  group by b,a

   The grouped que results:
   b            a
   ------------ -----------------
   GATO         UNO
   LOBO         DOS
   LOBO         UNO
   PATO         UNO
   PERRO        DOS
   PERRO        UNO
   POLLO        UNO
```

So, I want to count how many a's has b, for example LOBO has two results, or perro has two results after being grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count the `distinct` values of `a`, right? 
Then `group by b` only:

```
select b,count(distinct a) counter from @t  group by b
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c494de8775667c76f0e625ea40240c9f).
Results:

```
b     | counter
:---- | ------:
GATO  |       1
LOBO  |       2
PATO  |       1
PERRO |       2
POLLO |       1
```

If you want to count duplicates also then:

```
select b,count(a) counter from @t  group by b
```